# C++ Unordered Map Constant Time Access?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, stl, unordered-map

I am researching the C++ unordered_map container type. I am just verifying something I read from the C++ website on element access with [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/).

It says that the time complexity is usually constant, but worst case is linear time. Since my application must guarantee constant time access to elements inside of this map, I wanted to verify my understanding of this container.

Whenever my application accesses elements inside of this unordered_map, the object it is looking for is guaranteed to exist, so the container will never try to add in a missing element. Since I am only doing **look ups**, does that mean that the unordered_map will always give me **constant time access**? The **linear time** case is only for certain cases where an **insertion** will occur, is that correct?

Edit: The elements inside of the unordered_map are guaranteed to be unique. They hold the addresses of several unique objects existing in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lookup depends on whether there are hash collisions for any of the existing elements, in which case the elements get put in the same bucket and have to be linearly searched using the equality comparison. The worst case is that everything is in the same bucket.

So you *can* have a read-only map with linear look-up time complexity, but if you can guarntee no collisions for the existing elements, then you can guarantee O(1) look-up.

Comment: Ok, so every element in the unordered_map is also guaranteed to be unique, since it is just holding the addresses of several unique objects. That being side, there shouldn't be any hash collisions, correct?

Comment: @OliverSpryn No, it depends on the hashing function. That is a many-to-one function.

Comment: Ok, so do you have a suggestion for some type of container that can guarantee a constant time lookup (insertions don't matter) for non-contiguous keys? So, for instance, a `vector<>` or `array<>` would not work since those keys must be contiguous.

Comment: @OliverSpryn No, but if you know the domain of key values, you could look into implementing a perfect hash function to ensure no collisions. See for example [`gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Answer (score 4):

Wrong.

Hashmaps have `O(1)` time for both insert and lookup as long as there are no hash collisions. If there are hash collisions, the complexity is `O(m)` where `m` is the number of collisions with the requested hash - up to n if all hashes collide.

It is trivial to construct a case where all hashes collide, it is far from trivial to *avoid* this case, especially if there is a hostile attacker giving the keys.

If you want guaranteed time bounds, use a treemap, which is `O(log n)` for lookup and insertion